# Backbone.blazer routing with parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, marionette

I use [Backbone.Blazer](https://github.com/Betterment/backbone.blazer) plugin for my app routing. But i can't pass route parameters to the Route constructor. How can it be done?

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Blazer.Router.extend({
      routes: {
       '': new HomeRoute(),
       'accounts/:id': new AccRoute(), //how pass id parameter to the AccRoute constructor?
       'login': new LoginRoute()
      }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass route arguments to the constructor.

The route argument are passed to the execute function of the Route object.

```
var AccRoute = Backbone.Blazer.Route.extend({
    execute: function(routeParams) {
        console.log(routeParams.params[0]);
    }
});
```